# Restrict text field to mathematical expressions - Convert String to mathematical expression

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, expression

How can I restrict the input of a `TextField`such that it can only contain mathematical expressions?

Accepted inputs would be:

"3+5"

"-5 + 6"

"3/2(6*4)"

"6--5"

"+5-3"

etc..

And rejected inputs would be:

"5+++3"

"6(7)"

"6-6-+-7"

and so on.

Basically; the syntax I want it to be restricted to is the kind of syntax that programming languages normally use for evaluating mathematical expressions, kinda like the syntax input you'd expect from your everyday calculator.

I'm making a program in which I want the user to be able to input numbers and/or calculations into a text box, instead of having to use a calculator to do it and then arduously type out a number with 7 decimal places.

I've done a little look around and I've seen a lot of stuff involving Regex, postfix, BNF, and the like. A lot of it looked very complicated, too complex for my understanding, and none of it had anything to do with AS3.

However, I've had a thought about making this problem a whole lot simpler by just converting the string into a mathematical expression that AS3 can understand, and let Flash handle the errors using `try catch`, but I don't know how to do that either (`Number("3+5")`resulted to `NaN`).

I'm currently restricting text input to just numbers using `Event.CHANGE`, like this:

```
function Restrict(event:Event):void
        {

            if (event.currentTarget.text.indexOf(".") == -1)
            {
                event.currentTarget.restrict = "0-9.";
            }
            else
            {
                event.currentTarget.restrict = "0-9";

            }
        }
```

and it's seemed to work well so far.

I intend to implement this new restriction in this manner, but if there is a much more efficient way of restricting text input, please feel free to include it in a response.

Just to reiterate for clarity, I am asking how to implement functionality that will enable someone to input a mathematical expression into a `TextField`, and the program will register that input as an expression and calculate it.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: I've done a bit more research and I've stumbled upon a [Reverse Polish Notation](http://www.flashapi.org/rpnexp/) calculator/parser/utility class/library/thingy that looks very useful. Seems kinda similar to the `Executer` class that fsbmain mentioned, but it looks a lot simpler to use and easier for me to understand.

However the problem still remains that I'd have to find an efficient way to restrict the syntax of user input to mathematical expressions, but at least now I have at least two ways of converting the string into a number for calculations.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a tough question actually, even definition for `valid mathematical expressions` which you mentioned is very complicated itself, i.e. expression `6-6-+-7` is a valid from `as3` syntax point of view and gives result `7`.

Regarding second part of your question:

> converting the string into a mathematical expression that AS3 can understand

That's not possible to do with only native as3 means since `eval`-like functions are gone since `as2` time, but you can try to use some as3-written syntax translator, i.e. [`Executer`](https://github.com/junkbyte/flash-console/blob/master/src/com/junkbyte/console/core/Executer.as) from [`flash-console`](https://github.com/junkbyte/flash-console) project:

```
        var exec:Executer = new Executer();
        var res:* = exec.exec(this, "6-7");
        trace("exec = " + res); //output "-1"
```

Although it's failed with some complex expressions from your question:

```
        var exec:Executer = new Executer();
        var res:* = exec.exec(this, "6-6-+-7");
        trace("exec = " + res); //output "- 7"
```

Comment: This seems an interesting solution; I'll check it out.
However I have one query; I am not sure which evaluation of `"6-6-+-7"`is correct. To me, it looks like it should be 7, as 6-6 = 0, and then trying to subtract a positive negative number is just minus a negative, which is a positive, so it should be 7 in my eyes (or maybe my BIDMAS is slacking)

Comment: I agree, `-+-7` for me also should result in `7` (the same results gives as3 `asc2` compiler, but flash-console `Executor` gives `-7`